# Search a string for a word and reverse the string maintaining the case without using inbuilt functions

Tags: c#, c

I am really confused with this problem. Just to clear it out its not a homework but a question asked at the interview. I tried a lot to just get an idea on how to do it but was unable to do so

here is the problem

Suppose their is a string

```
"Patient Bond is the best bond in the world."
```

Now I want the word Patient and Bond to be find and reversed without using inbuilt functions and also maintaining the case.

The output should now be

```
"tneitaP dnoB is the best dnob in the world. "
```

I was using c but it was going way over my head on how to do it in it. So I switched to C# but the results were the same.

so can anyone guide me or even better if write the code.

I am a member from some time now and I know stack overflow does not solve the entire solution for me but just help me on the problems. But genuinely I am stuck at this problem and have no idea on what to do. 
So please help me out

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Seriously I have no Idea on how to do it. 
OK don't solve the question but maybe someone can give an idea on how to do it.

**Edit 2**

Now here is a solution that works perfectly but still got some built in functions in it
I am still working on coding them but for the time being and for the sake of opening the question again. **Now the question is can it be done by some other approach ?** Here is what I came up with.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ret = "";
            string ar = "Patient Bond is the best bond";
            foreach (string bar in ar.Split2(" "))
            {
                if (bar.ToLower() == "patient" || bar.ToLower() == "bond")
                    ret = ret + StringExtensions.ReverseMe(bar) + " ";
                else
                {
                    ret = ret + bar + " ";
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(ret);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }

    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> Split2(this string source, string delim)
        {
            // argument null checking etc omitted for brevity

            int oldIndex = 0, newIndex;
            while ((newIndex = source.IndexOf(delim, oldIndex)) != -1)
            {
                yield return source.Substring(oldIndex, newIndex - oldIndex);
                oldIndex = newIndex + delim.Length;
            }
            yield return source.Substring(oldIndex);
        }

        public static string ReverseMe(string abc)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int i = abc.Length - 1;
            while (i != -1)
            {
                sb.Append(abc[i--]);
            }
            string sbstring = sb.ToString();
            return sbstring;
        }
    }
```

I respect stack overflow as it made me learn so much that I couldn't had.I will say this that if a person asks for help don't just laugh at them saying you don't have skills try and help them out. I do the same and expect others to do so.I am sorry if I sound a bit harsh.

Comment: Why don't you post your code so far?

Comment: @KingsIndian because its not correct and I don't have a logic for it.

Comment: "without using inbuilt functions"... why don't you do everything in assembler? Frameworks and standard class libraries are here to avoid loosing time with low level function, in order to concentrate on business requirement fulfillment. Such questions in an interview will reveal who know the syntax. Not who can be a good engineer

Comment: Well, the first thing is to specify the desired output correctly: "tneitaP dnoB si eht tseb dnob ni eth dlrow." or "tneitaP dnoB si eht tseb dnob ni eth .dlrow" . The next is to characterize in words what a program would do to achieve that. Then code it. edit: Ok, I guess I misunderstood the task. I guess it's to find every instance of "patient" or "bond", regardless of case, and reverse it. So start with what it means to be an instance.

Comment: In C#, use `"Patient Bond is the best bond in the world.".Replace("Patient", "tneitaP").Replace("Bond", "dnoB")`

Comment: "because its not correct" -- irrelevant. If you don't start somewhere theny you'll never get anywhere ... except by expecting people here to do all your thinking for you. "I don't have a logic for it" -- well fix that; get "a logic". If you really can't, then forget about programming.

Comment: This sounds like an interview question, and you are trying to get someone else to answer the question for you. As starting, think about getting the words into a char array, and manipulating the array.  If you make use of unsafe c# it is even easier.

Comment: @SteveSolomon yes its an interview question and I failed in it that's why I am asking... and yes of course after trying for several hours.

Comment: @SteveSolomon It sounds that way because the OP *said* it was an interview question. Now that the interview is over, the OP wants to know how to answer it. My question is why someone with zero skills gets to such an interview in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but asking someone else kinda defeats the object of an interview test.

Comment: @ankit Why are you interviewing for a job in a field where you have no skills?

Comment: Fair point Jim. And missed the bit about it being an interview question.

Comment: @SteveSolomon Uh, no, it doesn't. There are several books on interview questions and how to answer them. People can learn skills from studying such books. However, they do have to have *some* skills to start with.

Comment: @JimBalter haha.. so nice of you.. I know I don't and asking for an idea is this site is all about isn't it? rather than mocking someone you could have helped out with an idea.

Comment: @SteveB "Such questions in an interview will reveal who know the syntax. Not who can be a good engineer " -- this is incorrect. Such questions explore whether someone has the programming logic skills that the OP clearly lacks.

Comment: @ankit You didn't answer my question. Why are you interviewing for a job for which you have no skills? If you know you have no skills, then the question goes double. And no, this site is not about giving you the skills you lack ... for that you need an education, which includes putting effort into solving assigned problems. Only after you have some basics will SO help you with *specific* programming problems.

Comment: why don't you just provide an answer? Seems to be a reasonable question after all.

Comment: Finally: "so can anyone guide me or **even better if write the code**" -- that is just **so so* wrong. Are you sure this isn't homework? Why else would you think it better for someone to write the code for you? That can't possibly help you pass an interview.

Comment: "one who helped by making fun of others" -- No one did that. "grow up guys" -- heavy projection.

Comment: I've flagged your rude comment.

Comment: @SteveB, The answer of using Replace on the string is not right, as the question said not to use inbuilt string functions. This is standard interview fodder.  If it was as simple as using string.Repleace, then there would be no need for the question.

Comment: "rather than mocking someone" -- I didn't mock you. "you could have helped out with an idea" -- I DID: " characterize in words what a program would do to achieve that ... start with what it means to be an instance". I did more for you than anyone else.

Comment: @ankitsuhail Nobody is intent on mocking you here. If you can show *some effort* in solving the problem and update the question with the same, I am willing to vote for re-open.

Comment: @KingsIndian Please now can you open the question so that I can get a better approach to the solution.

Comment: @Ankit You still need to describe problem you face than a just a plain code. I voted to re-open but other voters may expect more information (You need votes to re-open it)...

Comment: @KingsIndian yes I do understand... Now all I am asking for is to have a better solution than what I am doing. I will edit the question.

Comment: @JimBalter i hope I answered your question... I am not a zero skilled candidate and that is the reason I appeared for the interview. Everyone starts as a beginner and I just did. Thanks for the SO motivation.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing this in an interview, and they know you are a fresh grad, or inexperienced, then they are looking for your ability to analyze a problem. You have not provided in your question some attempt at analyzing the problem.

Here I describe one possible approach:

If the problem of ignoring case seems a little rough, solve the problem first assuming all letters are the same case.

Now, solve the problem using the built-in functions or standard library. This will demonstrate to the person conducting the interview that you understand the programming language, and know how to use the tools available.

After that is completed, you then look at the functions you used, and think about how you would implement them yourself. Sketch out the pseudo-code for each one.

Then, think about what changes would need to be done to allow those functions to work in a mixed case scenario.

Comment: thanks buddy.. I followed your approach.